# RSA Encryption From UWP App to Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I am passing a public key from a UWP application:

```
// Open the algorithm provider for the specified asymmetric algorithm.
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
// Create an asymmetric key pair.
CryptographicKey keyPair = objAlgProv.CreateKeyPair(512);
// Export the public key to a buffer for use by others.
// Default X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo format
IBuffer buffPublicKey = keyPair.ExportPublicKey();
byte[] publicKey = null;
CrytographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffPublicKey, out publicKey);
Conver.ToBase64String(publicKey);
```

The above string is sent to my Azure function App.

Here is a snippet of my Azure function app code:

```
// Algorithm = RsaPkcs1
    // Key Length = 512

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512))
    {
        byte[] bPublicKey = Convert.FromBase64String(publickey);
        byte[] bExponent = {1, 0, 1};

        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters() { Modulus = bPublicKey, Exponent = bExponent };
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        try
        {
            return RSA.Encrypt(sessionCode, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        } 
        catch (Exception errenc)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am trying to encrypt a value with public key and return.

I am running into issues with my Azure Function App and UWP Integration.

Azure side encrypts with the public key; no error is generated. Encrypted value is sent back to UWP. When I go to decrypt on the UWP side I get error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Any help is appreciated.  Having difficulty with the public key aspect on the azure side.

Thanks again

Comment: What exception / error did you get?

Comment: So the Azure side encrypts with the public key; no error is generated.  When I go to decrypt on the UWP side I get error

Comment: Sorry comment timed out...  So the Azure side encrypts with the public key; no error is generated.  Encrypted value is sent back to UWP.  When I go to decrypt on the UWP side I get error "Value does not fall within the expected range."  I feel like the problem may be my RSAParameters I am using in the Azure side.mment timed out...